i18n nextjs Internationalization Automatic Translation
Does anyone know how to do internationalisation with i18n nextjs with automatic translation instead of giving locales array like en, fr etc?
Or Instead of i18n nextjs, is there any other library or method to have automatic translation and route change for next.js

I'm not quite sure that I understood your problem correctly. However, I'll assume that your problem is the following:

You need auto-detection of the user language.
A hook that uses the previous value in order to generate the correct messages.

For that, I'd personally suggest using next-translate, with over 2.5k stars on Github, I believe that it is well-backed by the community and you'd probably find specifically what you're looking for.
The package supports Client and Server components, i18n style support, and straightforward documentation.
You can read more about auto langauge detection on the official next docs.

In next-translate, we have to give json object for each language which will be hand written and will not work dynamically. I want something like next-translate that can translate everything automatically and change the path as well. For example, if I am domain on english is www.example.com, and when I select the language as french, the path change to www.example.com/fr with translated language automatically.

Here is what I found: https://translate.i18next.com/, I haven't used it before but seems like what you are asking for
